# What does 'remove' mean in this context?

Tags: expressions

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQssMVQ3BQs&feature=youtu.be

At 4:14 on the video, she seems to say:

> "After that my dad says no no no, you removed yesterday, it is removed forever.”

What does that mean? Why did he say "no, no, no"? What did she remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video is of a woman who suffered an acid attack. She required multiple facial surgeries.

That usage of *remove* is just the usual one that means *to take something off*. She explained earlier that she covered her face in her daily life. It’s not clear but she attempted to live one day without the cover. Then she wanted to return to life with a cover. That’s why her dad protested and said “No.” He urged her that once she removed the cover, it must remain removed. They are not native English speakers, so there are grammatical mistakes in their speech. It should be “you removed **it** yesterday.”